# Computing mean and variance of chunks of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that is grouped and looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(
      [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]]
)
n_repeats = 4
```

The array contains three groups, here marked as 0, 1, and 2. Every group appears `n_repeats` times. Here `n_repeats=4`. Currently I do the following to compute the mean and variance of chunks of that array:

```
mean = np.array([np.mean(y[i: i+n_repeats], axis=0) for i in range(0, len(y), n_repeats)])
var = np.array([np.var(y[i: i+n_repeats], axis=0) for i in range(0, len(y), n_repeats)])
```

Is there a better and faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Given this specific example, shouldn't variance always be zero and mean be given by the "group id"?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Yes! But these numbers are just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, reshape and then use `.mean` and `.var` along the appropriate dimension:

```
>>> arr.reshape(-1, 4, 6)
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]]])
>>> arr.reshape(-1, 4, 6).mean(axis=1)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])
>>> arr.reshape(-1, 4, 6).var(axis=1)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: I really like this solution. It is also much faster than what I proposed!

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not know how many groups, or number of repeats, you can try:

```
>>> np.vstack([y[y == i].reshape(-1,y.shape[1]).mean(axis=0) for i in np.unique(y)])

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])

>>> np.vstack([y[y == i].reshape(-1,y.shape[1]).var(axis=0) for i in np.unique(y)])

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```